# How to get TinyMCE fullscreen mode to work with Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce-4

Just started using TinyMCE in an MVC razor project and very impressed with the HTML editing.

When I went to use it fullscreen however (using the following options)

```
$('#ApplicationHtmlTemplate').tinymce({
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: "code,pagebreak,fullpage,table,fullscreen,paste,spellchecker",
    toolbar1: "undo | redo | copy | paste | searchreplace | spellchecker | table | pagebreak | fullpage | fullscreen"
})
```

I noticed it appears underneath the bootstrap header bar:

[image]

What is the "correct" way to make the TinyMCE edit appear either underneath, or on top of, the Bootstrap nav bar? Preferably between the header and footer, but fullscreen would do.

I tried setting the top and/or margins of the `mce-fullscreen` class, using the style below, but this a) seems hacky and b) does not work as the height is the full screen so the scrollbars disappear off the bottom.

```
div.mce-fullscreen {
    top: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For "fullscreen" TinyMCE, *over the top of the Bootstrap nav bar*, you just need to set the `z-index` of the `.mce-fullscreen` class to greater than the nav bar's `z-index`.

If you are using `Less`, there is a variable in the bootstrap `variables.less` file called `@zindex-modal` used to define the Z-Index of Bootstrap modal popups. So you could do this:

```
div.mce-fullscreen {
    z-index: @zindex-modal;
}
```

Or, if you just use Bootstrap "raw" then:

```
div.mce-fullscreen {
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

**Note:** *This does not place it between the header and footer, so still looking for a better answer.*

Answer (score 3):

Add to your style the top as the height of your `nav-bar` header or footer:

```
div.mce-fullscreen {z-index: 1050;top: 51px!important;bottom: 51px!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

For tiny 5, when you toggle a bootstrap modal from some custom toolbar action then they appear under the editor and are not visible. If you exit the full screen mode, the modal is then visible (provided it hasn't been hidden beforehand).
So I changed the z-index value for the selector `.tox.tox-tinymce.tox-fullscreen` like it is given below.

```css
.tox.tox-tinymce.tox-fullscreen {
    z-index: 950;
}
```

This then makes the modals appear on top of the editor even when it is in full screen mode.

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple. Just add full screen plugins, it didn't mean to download additional plugins. Just add some more code where you include your TinyMCE editor.
Just add following code.

```
                 toolbar: "fullscreen",
                 plugins: ["fullscreen"],
```

if plugins already included then add with comma ",".
                     e.g.plugins: ["etc", "fullscreen"],

Comment: I will investigate and get back to you. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

Your plugin syntax is not correct:

```
$('#ApplicationHtmlTemplate').tinymce({
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: "code,pagebreak,fullpage,table,fullscreen,paste,spellchecker",
    toolbar1: "undo | redo | copy | paste | searchreplace | spellchecker | table | pagebreak | fullpage | fullscreen"
});
```

You must to separate the plugins using a blank space, not using a comma:

```
$('#ApplicationHtmlTemplate').tinymce({
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: "code pagebreak fullpage table fullscreen paste spellchecker",
    toolbar1: "undo | redo | copy | paste | searchreplace | spellchecker | table | pagebreak | fullpage | fullscreen"
});
```

Check here : https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup/#plugins

Comment: I don't think the commas make a difference. Their issue was more to do with a styling error when it was fullscreen.